# WKWebview not loading website fonts

Tags: c#, ios, swift

I created a WKWebview in my IOS application, to load a website that has custom fonts to display symbols.
The problem is that the font doesn't seem to be loaded as not symbols appears, and I also that some texts that have custom fonts have the wrong font.

Is there something to do for fonts to be loaded in a remote website ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was loading css and font files to my website from another website.
The solution was to put the file on my website. I imagine ios is securing some external requests...